# Table to dBase tool failure when converting .xls files

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, excel, dbf

Whenever I load my Excel 2010 worksheets into ArcMap 10 Table to dBASE tool, it fails, returning the error: "Failed to Copy Rows" The Copy Rows tool works just fine for me on a single document. There are no special characters or spaces in my file paths, workbook or worksheet names, or in column headers.

Has anybody else out there had an issue with this tool? Or is there a simple fix for this that I am missing?

Comment: Can you just export your table to dBASE format?

Answer (score 2):

There can be any number of reasons why ArcGIS can't create a dbf, so it may help if you post a sample Excel file that reproduces your problem, and also the exact error message that you get.

For instance, if I add an Excel sheet to ArcMap, and then call

```
arcpy.conversion.TableToDBASE("Sheet1$", r"c:\temp")
```

it fails with error **Failed to execute (CopyRows).** because of the (default) **$** sign. Renaming the table to Sheet2 in this case solves it.